# pixel perfect wordwrapping from hashmap that contains pixel width of characters

Tags: java

I'm writing a plugin for an application that uses a custom font, i made a hashmap containing each character as the key and the width in pixels as value(including 1 extra pixel for between characters). but i'm still having trouble finding a solution that doesn't feel like i don't know what i'm doing :P i tried checking other questions, but they all seem to be about length of the line in characters, or using external jars to handle standard fonts.

- trailing whitespaces may be trimmed (optional).
- words that don't fit the line need to go to the next line.
- words that are bigger then an entire line should be split after the last character that can be on a line. (with only 112 pixels wide as linelength this should take in account that - a word might need to be splitted multiple times).
- splits should be joined with linebreaks in between.
- the input is a string with some existing linefeed characters.
- the max line length in pixels = 112.

if there is a better way to aproach this then a hashmap please don't mind ignoring that.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support only ASCII or ISO-8859-1 then a simple array of widths indexed by the binary character value would be a better choice. If you need to support Unicode then a Map is better since an array would be quite large and sparse (i.e. mostly empty).

Give the 112 pixel width, you must be writing this for an embedded display, so you probably don't care about hyphenation, splitting on syllables, and such niceties.  Depending on how many lines your display has you might want to consider setting a minimum threshold for splitting a word, say 25% of its width.  I.e. if you can't get at least 25% of the letters on the line, break the entire word to the next line and leave whitespace at the end of the previous line.  But that's an aesthetic decision that may not be a consideration given the limited space.

Comment: The aplication uses cp-437: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 a unicode charset of 255 chars. Niceties are indeed not that important. i don't have a hard line limit though. so a map i guess. any tips on processing the string?

Comment: If your font has to support character codes 0-255 only, then use an array.  Just scan your string adding up widths until you exceed 112 pixels and break between the prior and current characters.

Comment: ... uhm, yeah... i guess all the previous semi-related examples i saw made me overthink this way to much. Thanks bro. less then 15 rep so i can't vote. :( i'll be sure to get back if i get there ;)